# UI feel and look in Titanium, PhoneGap compared to native

Tags: android, iphone, cordova, titanium, smartphone

I am about to decide which way to push our smartphone development. 
I have read numerous articles about these technologies. I have also created test apps, but wanted to be 100% sure that I get this right.

1. I am not able to create EXACTLY the same look and feel like native app in PhoneGap because it runs in WebView Controler. And the webish look and feel is as far as I will get with this tech. correct? 
   (In the example app I have created with PG, the look might be similar, but there is a delay when i click on buttons and the animation is not so fluent as in native apps)
2. Latest Titanium seems to have changed its approach to WebView, to remedy that lack of look and feel of native apps. My question is (I havent tested this myself). Can I create EXACTLY the same look and feel of an native app with Titanium?

EXACTLY is the key word. I mean can a person tell a difference if app was created with Titanium? because I can definitely tell that app was created with PG.

Final goal is the UX, ppl sense this things, and on smartphones anything that is webish and is suppose to be appish is a bad UX i believe.

Thanks

Comment: Keep in mind that most smartphone users probably won't notice a difference between native and PG since it doesn't bother them. They can't tell if an app is created with Titanium because they don't know anything about titanium.

Comment: People don't have to know about the platform it was build on to feel the platform it was build on... Small annoyances can be enough for the app to fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compared to PG Titanium is more Native like UI experience but it's kinda problematic for Android.Since it's originally intended for IOS.

Titanium for Android is pretty buggy and can mess you up and the thing that you have to come up with workarounds and if you cant find any then you are stuck.

But if you are okay with that and i can easily advise that Titanium is way to go though it's nearly native (not exactly) which close to exactly.I dont think an average user would understand Titanium .

Answer (score 1):

2) yes, since titanium uses the original UI. your javascript code is wrapped to native Objective c code that creates native elements. only constraint is that your are not as flexible as with real native code written by yourself. but you can write native modules and add them to your projekt. so you're able to expand your project with custom UI too.